# pmyAdmin how to overcome 2Mb import limit?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I try to import my database tables to local XAMMP dev computer. But i keep  hitting 2MB  phpMyAdmin limit (Max: 2,048KiB). I try to set all limits to php.ini without luck. So stypid question how i todo this?

Comment: What properties did you changes?

Comment: Probably wrong ones :) .... I except your answer in 10 minutes.....

Comment: They was:
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize

Comment: Some kind stypid time limit ... 1 minute...

Comment: ok got lost what i changed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *probably* three properties that need to be changed.

**php.ini**

> upload_max_filesize = 16M
>   post_max_size = 16M

**my.cnf**

> max_allowed_packet = 16M

After adjusting these commands I suggest a restart of both services, however a reload should be the only thing necessary.